# How to sync easily between a master database from Google Cloud SQL and a master database from Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql

I've created a master - slave (replication) in Google Cloud SQL. 
I've also created a master - slave (replication) in Amazon RDS.

I want to sync two master MysQL from Google Cloud SQL and Amazon RDS. What's the approach can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, just adding replication masters to the two servers should work over the MySQL protocol, and without needing any additional configuration.

You can review the procedures at the below links for details on each side of the process:

1. [AWS - How can I replicate an Amazon RDS for MySQL instance by using binary logs to an on-premises environment?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/replicate-amazon-rds-mysql-on-premises/)
2. [GCP - Configuring external replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-replica)
3. [GCP - Replicating from an external server](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external)

Comment: That would be master - slave architecture by using external replica. What I want to achieve is syncing two master MySQL from AWS & GCP.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a master-master architecture where one master is in AWS and the other in GCP, and both instances are running via the respective platforms' managed database services. In that case you would have to set up the replication as AWS master is slave of GCP instance, and the GCP instance is a slave of the AWS master. Do note that writing to both instances at the same time is not recommended.